# What precautions should be taken for storing HTML in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should be kept as HTML tags in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867204/how-should-be-kept-as-html-tags-in-database)

I will store HTML code through admin page of my php program. I use prepared statements in PDO for storing. But before that, do i need to use htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() ?

Or by storing html using prepared statement will work fine ? Any overheads later ?

Later this html is used to display as content inside a HTML page and this content from database should render as HTML itself.

Comment: And the difference between both functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For real, in your case no precautions should be taken.**

There is no need for `htmlspecialchars()` as you want to display html and no need to use `htmlentities()` if the character set of your site is equal to the one you use in your database. Also you don't have to escape the string on your own as prepared statements will take care of that.

However, `htmlentities()` will not cause any harm but using it is just waste of performance. The easiest way to deal with the character set is to simply use UTF-8 to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: You do however need to escape the input, either by using PDO (recommended) or by using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Quoute: I use prepared statements in PDO for storing.

Comment: And if the text stored in the database contains `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 3):

you should use htmlspecialchars on output, not when storing.. pdo will handle the safety for storing the input

Comment: basically prepared statements will handle the escaping of your strings.. you need to use something like htmlspecialchars when you output to be sure that content provided by some user doesn't get parsed, this way protecting your website from things like javascript written by your users

Comment: Quote: Later this html is used to display as content inside a HTML page and this content from database should render as HTML itself. If you use htmlspecialchars() you will get text output of the html code.

Comment: the answer does not suggest using htmlspecialchars **every time** if that is why you choose to vote down. it just states that the purpose of the mentioned (by the op) function is to escape output, not input. this way, if you have content provided by users, you can be sure, for example, that javascript code that they save doesn't execute.. the same thing is stated in the clarification added in the first comment ("[..]that content provided by some user[..]")

Comment: You suggest to use htmlspecialchars() for displaying which does not reflect what the OP had asked for and don't mention the problematics related to the character set. Your answer more likely fits to a question with the title "How to prevent displaying html for some users". Also it is a guess that his admin panel have users and he want to prevent some of them to get html displayed. Therefore this should be written as a comment due it's an advice. I hope i have clarified my standpoint and you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

just refer to the old posts [Store HTML into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641561/store-html-into-mysql-database)

[How to store html in a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256477/how-to-store-html-in-a-mysql-database)

this will give you a good solution.