# data to be given to plot on graph

Tags: jquery, mysql

am using fushion charts. in that data for chart has been given as folllows

```
   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                        var combiDYData = '<chart     caption="Weekly Sales Summary" subCaption="Revenue & Quantity" xAxisName="Weeks"  pyAxisName="Amount" sYaxisName="Quantity" numberPrefix="$" placeValuesInside="1"> \n\
                        <categories>\n\
                            <category Label="Week1"/>\n\
                            <category Label="Week2"/>\n\
                            <category Label="Week3"/>\n\
                            <category Label="Week4"/>\n\
                            <category Label="Week5"/>\n\
                            <category Label="Week6"/>\n\
                        </categories>\n\
                        <dataset seriesName="Revenue">\n\
                            <set  value="264000" /> \n\
                            <set  value="346000" /> \n\
                            <set  value="440000" /> \n\
                            <set  value="267000" /> \n\
                            <set  value="267000" /> \n\
                            <set  value="267000" /> \n\
                        </dataset>\n\
                        <dataset seriesName="Quantity" ParentYAxis="s" showValues="0"> \n\
                            <set  value="1600" /> \n\
                            <set  value="1900" /> \n\
                            <set  value="2400" /> \n\
                            <set  value="1600" /> \n\
                            <set  value="1600" /> \n\
                            <set  value="1600" /> \n\
                        </dataset>\n\
                        </chart>';
```

how can i get the same data from database. please anyone suggest me how we can store in db and how to retrieve it inorder to get the data in the same way. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for what type to use to store in database, if it is So:

LONGTEXT is probably excessive -- it allows data sizes up to 4GB.

MEDIUMTEXT allows 16MB.

TEXT allows 64KB.

TINYTEXT allows only 255 characters.

Very few HTML documents are going to be 64KB in size, so a TEXT ought to be suitable for you. If you really want to be safe, go for a MEDIUMTEXT.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. if i store data in mysql can i get the data in the same form as mentioned above. if so how to get in that way

Comment: can you first try using SELECT statement like 'select column name from table'; then let me know the output, will check if any errors

Comment: i gave code as follows. but the output is getting as invalid data category label = [
                                <?php
                                $query = mysql_query("select * from product") or die(mysql_error());
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "'" . $row['name'] . "'" . ','; ?> 
                                <?php }; ?>
                                ];

Comment: Hey, just refer this, may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256477/how-to-store-html-in-a-mysql-database